# Device to measure 3-phase electrical power consumption

Tags: electrical-engineering

For a three phase air-conditioner, what is the easiest way to measure the power consumption? Is there any off-the-shelf device that can get the job done and output the measurements through RS485 (Modbus-RTU)?

Comment: other than a watt meter?  A clamp-on will measure amps but not the power factor.

Comment: Many meters capable of this with large displays and capability of connecting to computers using various methods.

Comment: I was looking at something like this [link](https://www.chinahao.com/product/5785417610/)